# Fitting curve with scipy curve fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit data, but it doesn't fit properly at the "knee". The equation is `y = 8*A*(0.1875*(x+B))^(1/3)`, where `A` is in the range `[0,1]` and `B` is in the range `[1,25]`. I am using the SciPy `curve_fit` function for the fitting.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

plt.close("all")

def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()

    return idx

def curve_func(x, A, B):
    return 8*A*(0.1875 * (x + B))**(1/3)

x = np.linspace(0, 1000)
y = 8*0.1875*x**(1/3)

# Fit the curve
initial_guess = [0.2, 16]  # Initial guess for the parameters

dep = 5
pos_dep = find_nearest(x[::-1], dep)
params, pcov = curve_fit(curve_func, 
                         x[::-1][:pos_dep]/10, 
                         y[::-1][:pos_dep], 
                         bounds = ([0,1],[1,25]))

# Extract the fitted parameters
A_fit, B_fit= params

# Generate the curve using the fitted parameters
curve_fit_data = curve_func(x, A_fit, B_fit)

# Plot the original data and the fitted curve
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x[::-1][:pos_dep], y[::-1][:pos_dep], label="Data")
plt.plot(x[::-1][:pos_dep], curve_fit_data[::-1][:pos_dep], color="r", label="Fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run and test.

Comment: @jared I am nor sure how to upload the text file. But x = np.linspace(0,1000)
y = 8*.1875*x**(1/3) could be used instead.

Comment: (1) Why are you only using a subset of the data and reversing it? (2) Is your issue that the fit is offset from the data? If so, that's because you fit it using `x/10` but then evaluate it using the undivided `x`, i.e. you should have `curve_fit_data = curve_func(x/10, A_fit, B_fit)` to be consistent.